# Angular UI Bootstrap datepicker opening two datepicker on single click?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm referring this one [example on Official site](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker)

Whenever I clicked on calendar icon it open two date-pickers. What I want is single datepicker for single date input.

Comment: Try wrapping it using an object scope to create its own scope, i.e. the value of `$scope.data` is `$scope.calendar.data`, and the same goes for any function (especially the on click one)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind different variables to the `is-open` attribute as following:

```
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="isOpened1" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isOpened1 = !isOpened1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>

        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="date" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="isOpened2" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isOpened2 = !isOpened2"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
```

Then, handle the click event to change the bound variable.

[See how it works](http://plnkr.co/edit/AE0MT8K0Mi642qetbmsN?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

[Use this code.](http://plnkr.co/edit/pqYcXY9Jz5C6wU9xxXKN?p=preview)

For the two boxes they gives two calender box. use single one.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<style>
  .full button span {
    background-color: limegreen;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
  .partially button span {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
</style>
<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
    <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>

    <h4>Inline</h4>
    <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
      <uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm" custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)"></uib-datepicker>
    </div>

    <h4>Popup</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Format:</label> <select class="form-control" ng-model="format" ng-options="f for f in formats"><option></option></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="today()">Today</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="setDate(2009, 7, 24)">2009-08-24</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="toggleMin()" uib-tooltip="After today restriction">Min date</button>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```